# Check sum of two values in two different tables before INSERT

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the tables that are in the picture and what I want to do is make sure that students can't study more courses than 45 points per school year.

So I want to do a check every time something is inserted into the `Studies` table, so that the student's total points in `Studies` and `HasStudied` combined doesn't go past 45 points within one year.

So if a student has 40 points combined in `Studies` and `HasStudied`, inserting a new row for this student in the `Studies` table that would lead to them getting above 45 points shouldn't be possible.

Not sure how I'd do this.

[How my tables look now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ax35W.jpg)

EDIT

Since my lecturer said nothing about database performance and such, I did the following.

I do  INSERT as normal but after the insert is complete, I make a DELETE with a condition that checks so score isn't equal to or above 45. I would also like it to print a message if the delete goes through saying "Students cannot study more then 45 points)

I have the following code but it deletes all rows in the Studies table instead of just the ones with sPoints above or equal to 45

```
DELETE FROM Studies 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT stID, SUM(sPoints) totalpoint
FROM (SELECT stID, sPoints 
        FROM Studies
        UNION ALL
        SELECT stID, sPoints 
        FROM HasStudied) derp
GROUP BY stID
HAVING SUM(sPoints) >= 45)
```

Answer (score 1):

How you are checking values from two tables, you can use a [trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql) to check

Or you can use a more complex checking using a [UDF](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/using-udf-check-constraint-validate-column)

Comment: Since my lecturer didn't say anything about performance.. I did what is stated in the OP but still cannot get it to function properly